# R read.table, each row in a bracket

Tags: r

I have a lot of data files formatted like this:

```
{1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3}
{0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 4, 2}
{1, 2, 3, 7, 5, 8, 6}
```

Is there a way for `read.table` (or whatever import function) to read this data? There's no space between the brackets and the numbers so I can't treat them as character columns.

Comment: if your data is stroed in test1.txt, then `read.table(text=gsub("[}{]", "", readLines("test1.txt")), sep=",")`... must be a dup

Comment: On linux, `data.table::fread("cat file | tr -d '{}'")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write out your data

```
txt <- 
"{1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3}
{0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 4, 2}
{1, 2, 3, 7, 5, 8, 6}"

cat(txt, file="test1.txt")
```

Read in your data

```
read.table(text=gsub("[}{]", "", readLines("test1.txt")), sep=",")
```

---

`readLines` reads the data in as a text line.

```
readLines("test1.txt")
#[1] "{1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3}" "{0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 4, 2}" "{1, 2, 3, 7, 5, 8, 6}"
```

You can then use `gsub` to remove the curly brackets.

```
gsub("[}{]", "", readLines("test1.txt"))
#[1] "1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3" "0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 4, 2" "1, 2, 3, 7, 5, 8, 6"
```

You can the use `read.table`, almost as usual, but you pass the string to the `text` argument.

---

Also from (aka) Hadd E. Nuff, for use on linux systems

```
data.table::fread("cat test1.txt | tr -d '{}'")
```

and in the same way, without packages

```
read.table(pipe("cat test1.txt | tr -d '{}'"), sep=",")
```